# How do I make Front Ortho the Active Camera?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

How can I render my scene so that the camera is in the same spot as the front orthographic viewport? The Front Orthographic view is exactly how I want it rendered, not by pressing <kbd>NumPad 0</kbd>.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go to the front view by pressing <kbd>NumPad 1</kbd>. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad 0</kbd> to set the camera to the current view. Then switch the camera from perspective to orthographic.

[image: Ortho]

Unlike with a perspective camera, the local Z location of an orthographic camera is irrelevant. To render more or less of your scene, you must change the *orthographic scale*.

[image: Scale]