# Possible To Create These Isometric Architectural Diagrams? Any Tutorials Out There?

Tags: modeling, animation, import, extrude

[VIDEO LINKS HERE](https://vimeo.com/324207960#t=30s)

Been looking high and low for a solution to creating a diagrammatic animation like this. I have use of SketchUp, Lumion, Rhino, Adobe Suite - but not 3DS Max which is what I imagine this was originally made in. Would really love to know if I could make it in Blender and if there were any basic tutorials on how to create this style? Always wanted to learn Blender!

Comment: can you be more specific? Blender has an Isometric camera and can animate in the way the video shows buildings popping up and down.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) Read also: [What is the problem with posting an image (or link) and asking “How do I do this?”](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this)

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135306/setting-up-an-isometric-view

Comment: Rob! Thanks for the comment. See the video link in the original post to see exactly what I'm talking about. I mainly looking for the ability to move the camera around while animation basic diagrammatic shapes. Have any tutorial resources on this?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Asking for resources or links to tutorials is considered off topic here. If you can, rephrase your question to focus on the specific parts you are having difficulties, or return once you have started

Comment: Ah, was unaware. Where would be a good place to ask for tutorials on the forum?

Comment: Google. There is also [Blender Artists](https://blenderartists.org) and [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=blender.stackexchange.com)